# Getting Git init to automatically use SSH

Tags: git, github

I'm using Github SSH to push my files. I have ssh configured, but every time I init a new repo I need to change the .git/config file manually to change

```
url = https://github.com/alex3wielki/project-setup.git
```

to

```
url = ssh://git@github.com/alex3wielki/project-setup.git
```

but still I have to add my credentials on the first push. Is there any way to make it automatic?

Comment: Use key-based auth and ssh-agent

Comment: I am using an SSH agent

Comment: When you init a repo it doesn't have a remote.  Do you mean when you *clone* the repo?  When you clone the repo, you tell it what URL to use; if you are having to change it from an HTTP URL to an SSH URL, then you are cloning from an HTTP URL; so clone from the SSH URL instead

Comment: I'm doing:

`git init`
`git add .`
`git commit -m "message"`
`git add origin` - link from github repo init
`git push`

I'm not cloning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
git remote add origin "link from github repo"
```

use ssh URL instead of https URL. You can get ssh URL when you're logged-in into your github account. Or you can manually translate https URL to ssh, it's quite obvious:

```
https://github.com/alex3wielki/project-setup.git
```

to

```
git@github.com:alex3wielki/project-setup.git
```

I.e. replace `https://` with `git@` and replace the first `/` with `:`.

To get ssh URL for a repo click **Clone or download** button. A dialog opens; switch the protocol from HTTPS to SSH; copy the URL to clipboard and paste it to the command line. See https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/

Comment: Can I tell github to always give me ssh link?

Comment: Not in browser's URL bar, of course. I updated my answer, see the last paragraph.

Comment: Ok. I click the `New repository` plus next to my icon in the top right. Is there a way for it to give me the `ssh` link when it's giving me the commands?

Comment: As far as I remember github shows these commands only when one creates the first repository for a user or an organization. It's a rather rare event.

Comment: So I'll essentially need to edit the link every time?

Comment: I edit URLs because I don't like github UI; for me it's simpler to edit command line. If you don't like editing you can get ssh URL after the repository has been created.

Answer (score 5):

Yes

If Git prompts you for a username and password every time you try to interact with GitHub, you're probably using the HTTPS clone URL for your repository.

Using an HTTPS remote URL has some advantages: it's easier to set up than SSH, and usually works through strict firewalls and proxies. However, it also prompts you to enter your GitHub credentials every time you pull or push a repository.

You can configure Git to store your password for you like this below :

Store your credential using [this](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/)

Caching your GitHub password in Git (Tip: You need Git 1.7.10 or newer to use the credential helper) :

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

In case you want to delete your credential :

[Deleting](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/) your credentials via the command line

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com
protocol=https
```

Comment: I did the whole SSH setup. As I wrote in my post I'm using ssh. The problem is, newly initialized .git folders use the https, instead of ssh, and I have to edit them by hand.